# Insert large txt into sql

Tags: sql-server, windows

I need to insert multiple "large" txt files into SQL server and this will be my first time handling this amount of data.

The current method at my workplace its  the import/export wizard which takes around a week on avg per table according to my coworkers (i think thats waaaaay too much).

The 3 biggest tables are between 70-140 million rows with 50-150 columns.

Ive been reading about bcp / bulkinsert but dont really know how to implement and which one is faster. The only thing i got is that its slower to insert the data with constraints and should add them after the table is created.

So my question is: Which tool its better for the task and what can i do to improve the performance?.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I believe Import/Export Wizard uses bcp behind the scenes.  A few of the things you can do to help improve performance are:

- Disable/remove constraints
- Disable/remove triggers
- Disable/remove indexes
- Use Minimal Logging Database Recovery model

A few other things to keep in mind is that performance will not be as fast if the table you are inserting in is largely populated.  You can also bulk insert parts of the file in parallel.

Here is a link with more info and other ways to optimize:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx

Hope this helps